# How to achieve currency/ fuel price format (0,00) from left to right in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am currently developing an app where user needs to input fuel price in 0,00 format where after first digit shows comma and it is limited only to input 3 digits.
Does anybody have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `objc` function inside your `UIViewController` class:

```
@objc func format_textfield(_ sender:UITextField){
    var str:String = sender.text!
    if str.count>0 && Array(str)[0] == ","{
        sender.text = String(str.suffix(from: str.index(str.startIndex,offsetBy: 1)))
        str = sender.text!
    }
    if str.count > 4 {
        sender.text = String(str.prefix(4))
    }else if str.count > 1 && Array(str)[1] != ","{
        sender.text = String(str[..<str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)])+","+String(str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)...])
    }
}
```

Then, add the function as a target for your `UITextField` like this (this can be done in the `viewDidLoad()` method):

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(format_textfield(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Comment: Great! Nice solution but just one thing , when I want to delete I can not delete all charachters , example I texted 1,99 but when I delete it  with numberic pad keyboard it stays by 1, could you please check it why?

Comment: Give me some minutes and I'll edit my answer with a better solution :)

Comment: Ok , nice to hear that :)

Comment: Done! It can still be improved but I think it works well enough. Maybe you can make the improvements. Things to improve: when you delete the first number, the text cursor is moved to the right.

Comment: Works like a charm I appreciate it :)

Comment: Also, allow the user to only add numbers. Because, at this moment, the user is able to add letters and symbols. You can set the keyboard type to numeric only.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did